# how can I get the metadata of a report with simplesalesforce

Tags: python, salesforce, simple-salesforce

I need to know the metadata of a SF report (e.g. which objects are used). Is there a way to do this with simplesalesforce in a similar way as e.g. `sf.describe.Account()`?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what metadata you want to see, but the following code will return an `OrderedDict` with information about a given report.

```
from simple_salesforce import Salesforce

sf_conn = Salesforce(username="your_username", password=PL.return_password("your_password"), security_token=PL.return_password("your_token")) 
report_id = "your_report_id"
sf_conn.restful('analytics/reports/{}'.format(report_id))
```

Here is [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_analytics.meta/api_analytics/sforce_analytics_rest_api_getreportrundata.htm) for what information is returned in the `OrderedDict`.